# fadeIn certain object after appending to div?

Tags: jquery

How do I make the appended HTML fadeIn() without fading in all objects of the same class? This function will be used several times, and I cannot add an ID to the objects created, or it would conflict with something I will soon add. Thanks if you help

CSS:

```
        #log {
            background-color:#4D4D4D;
            height:400px;
            width:600px;
            left:31%;
            position:fixed;
            z-index:-10;
            margin-top:-10px;
        }
        .logArrow {
            height:24px;
            width:24px;
            background: url('http://www.industus.com/img/log1.png') center no-repeat;
            margin-top:10px;
            display:none;
        }
        .logMsg {
            color:white;
            display:none;
        }
        .inline {
            display:inline-block;
            margin-left:5px;
        }
```

jQuery:

```
function log(message) {
                $("<div class='logArrow inline'></div><div class='logMsg inline'>"+message+"</div><br />").appendTo("#log").fadeIn(3000);
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="log">
</div>
```

Comment: Can't you just add `.fadeIn()` after `.appendTo('#log')`?

Comment: I tried; that does not work.

Comment: It doesn't do anything at all when I add it

Comment: Can you add an 'empty' class to those elements that you wish to fadeIn?

Comment: [Already answered here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6265778/can-i-appendto-in-jquery-but-have-it-fade-in-rather-than-instantly-appear).

Add `.hide()` before `.appendTo()`.

Comment: You are assigning the class `inline` to your `div`s that you are appending. That class has `display:inline-block;` this is overriding the `display:none;` which you are setting with the other classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should wrap the content you're inserting in a container div and set that one to `display: none`, then call `.fadeIn()` on that:

## [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/42At6/1/)

CSS:

```
#log {
    background-color:#4D4D4D;
    height:400px;
    width:600px;
    left:31%;
    position:fixed;
    z-index:-10;
    margin-top:-10px;
}
.logArrow {
    height:24px;
    width:24px;
    background: url('http://www.industus.com/img/log1.png') center no-repeat;
    margin-top:10px;
    /* REMOVE display: none; FROM HERE */
}
.logMsg {
    color:white;
    /* REMOVE display: none; FROM HERE */
}
.inline {
    display:inline-block;
    margin-left:5px;
}
.message { /* ADD THIS CLASS */
    display: none;
}
```

jQuery:

```
function log(message) {
    $('<div class="message"></div>')
        .append('<div class="logArrow inline"></div>')
        .append('<div class="logMsg inline">'+ message +'</div>')
        .appendTo("#log")
        .fadeIn();
}
```

Comment: Or keep his original code and just add `.hide()` before `.appendTo()`.

Comment: @Corey: My answer is better :-)

Comment: @Travesty3 if having more lines of code means better, then yes :-)

Comment: @Corey: Number of lines of code is not important. Clarity of code is much, MUCH more important. It's much easier to see what's going on with the way I've written it, as opposed to one really long line. And I've also addressed the issue of the `display` CSS property being overridden by the `inline` class, further clearing up the code.

Comment: @Corey: *sigh*...agree to disagree